# image won't upload correctly in web browser from mongodb database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ejs

I managed to store some user info in mongodb database. When I tried to retrieve it and display it in the browser all fields are correct except the image file. The image is type Object in database and has 2 fields: data : Binary('..... and contentType : "image/png". When I tried to convert it in the ejs file the browser shows broken image icon. I also inspected the page and I found this error: "Failed to load resource: net :: ERR_INVALID_URL data:users[i]/image/png;base64,%OA [object Object]"; what should I change so image is loaded correctly?

**ejs file for displaying data:**

```
<% for(var i=0;i<users.length;i++) {%>
<tr>
    <td><%= i+1 %></td>

    <% if(users[i].profile_picture) {%>
    <td>
        <div>
            <img src="data:users[i]/<%=users[i].profile_picture.contentType%>;base64,
                    <%=users[i].profile_picture.data.toString('base64')%>">
        <div>
    </td>
    <% } else {%>

        <td> </td>
    <% } %>   


<td><%= users[i].name %></td>
<td><%= users[i].email %></td>
<td><%= users[i].gender %></td>
<%# .replace(/\n/g, '<br/>') %>
<td><%- users[i].favorite_movies? users[i].favorite_movies.replace(/\n/g, '<br/>') :'' %></td>
<td>
    <a href="/update-user?id=<%= users[i]._id %>" class="btn border-shadow update">
        <span class="text-gradient"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></span>
    </a>
    <a class="btn border-shadow delete" data-id=<%= users[i]._id %>>
        <span class="text-gradient"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></span>
    </a>
</td>
```

**model.js file:** (mongo scheme)

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    profile_picture: {
        data: Buffer, 
        contentType: String
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    gender: String,
    favorite_movies: {
        type: String,
        text: true
    }
})

const Userdb = mongoose.model('userdb', schema);

module.exports = Userdb;
```

**controller.js file: **

```
var multer = require('multer');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
  
var Storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, 'uploads/')
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, Date.now() + file.originalname);
    }
});
  
var upload = multer({ storage: Storage });


var Userdb = require('../model/model');

//create and save new user
exports.upload = upload.single('image');

exports.create = (req, res, next)=>{
    //validate request
    if(!req.body){
        res.status(400).send({ message : "Content cannot be empty!"});
        return;
    }

    //new user
    const user = new Userdb({
        profile_picture : {
            data: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname + '/../../uploads/' + req.file.filename)),
            contentType: 'image/png'
        },
        name : req.body.name,
        email : req.body.email,
        gender : req.body.gender,
        favorite_movies : req.body.favorite_movies
    })

    //save user in the database
    user
      .save(user)
      .then(data=>{
          //res.send(data)
          res.redirect('/add-user');
      })
      .catch(err=>{
          res.status(500).send({
              message : err.message || "Some error occurred while creating a create operation"
          });
      });
}

//retrieve and return all users/ retrieve and return a single user
exports.find = (req,res)=>{
    if(req.query.id){
        const id = req.query.id;

        Userdb.findById(id)
         .then(data=>{
             if(!data){
                 res.status(404).send({message : "Not found user with id " + id})
             }else{
                 res.send(data)
             }
         })
         .catch(err=>{
             res.status(500).send({message : "Error retrieving user with id " + id})
         })
    }else{
    Userdb.find()
    .then(user=>{
        res.send(user)
    })
    .catch(err=>{
        res.status(500).send({message : err.message || "Error occurred while retriving user information"})
    })
    }
}

//update a new identified user by user id
exports.update = (req,res)=>{
    if(!req.body){
        return res
            .status(400)
            .send({message : "Data to update cannot be empty"})
    }

    const id = req.params.id;
    Userdb.findByIdAndUpdate(id, req.body, {useFindAndModify : false})
     .then(data=>{
         if(!data){
             res.status(404).send({message : `Cannot update user with ${id}. Maybe user not found!`})
         }else{
             res.send(data)
         }
     })
     .catch(err=>{
         res.status(500).send({message : "Error update user information"})
     })
}

//delete a user with specified user id in the request
exports.delete = (req,res)=>{
    const id = req.params.id;

    Userdb.findByIdAndDelete(id)
     .then(data=>{
         if(!data){
             res.status(404).send({message : `Cannot delete with id ${id}. Maybe id is wrong`})
         }else{
             res.send({
                 message : "User was deleted successfully!"
             })
         }
     })
     .catch(err=>{
         res.status(500).send({
             message : "Could not delete User with id=" + id
         });
     });
}
```

**server.js:**

```
const express = require('express');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const bodyparser = require("body-parser");
const path = require('path');

const connectDB = require('./server/database/connection');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();

dotenv.config({path : 'config.env'})
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080

//log requests
app.use(morgan('tiny'));

//mongodb connection
connectDB();

//parse request to body-parser
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended : false}))
app.use(bodyparser.json())

//set view engine
app.set("view engine", "ejs")
//app.set("views", path.resolve(__dirname, "views/ejs"))

//load assets
app.use('/css', express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "assets/css")))
app.use('/img', express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "assets/img")))
app.use('/js', express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "assets/js")))

//load routers
app.use('/', require('./server/routes/router'))

app.listen(PORT, ()=>{console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:${PORT}`)});
```

**router.js:**

```
const express = require('express');
const route = express.Router();
route.use(express.static(__dirname+"/uploads/"));

const services = require('../services/render');
const controller = require('../controller/controller');

route.get('/', services.homeRoutes);
route.get('/add-user', services.add_user);
route.get('/update-user', services.update_user);

//API
route.post('/api/users', controller.upload, controller.create);
route.get('/api/users', controller.find);
route.put('/api/users/:id', controller.upload, controller.update);
route.delete('/api/users/:id', controller.delete);

module.exports = route
```

**render.js:**

```
const axios = require('axios');
//const { response } = require('express');

exports.homeRoutes = (req,res) => {
    //make a get request to /api/users
    axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/users')
     .then(function(response){
         res.render('index', {users : response.data});
     })
     .catch(err=>{
         res.send(err);
     })
}

exports.add_user = (req,res) => {
    res.render('add_user');
}

exports.update_user = (req,res) => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/users', {params : {id : req.query.id}})
     .then(function(userdata){
         res.render("update_user", {user : userdata.data})
     })
     .catch(err=>{
         res.send(err);
     })
}
```

**index.ejs:**

```
<!--include header-->
  <%- include('include/_header')%>
<!--/include header-->



<!-- Main Site -->
    <main id="site-main">
      <div class="container">
          <div class="box-nav d-flex justify-between">
              <a href="/add-user" class="border-shadow">
                  <span class="text-gradient">New User <i class="fas fa-user"></i></span>
              </a>
          </div>
          <!-- form handling -->
          <form action="/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
              <table class="table">
                  <thead class="thead-dark">
                      <tr>
                          <th>ID</th>
                          <th>Profile Picture</th>
                          <th>Name</th>
                          <th>@Email</th>
                          <th>Gender</th>
                          <th>Favorite Movies</th>
                          <th>Action</th>
                      </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    <%- include('include/_show')%>
                  </tbody>
              </table>
          </form>
      </div>
  </main>
<!-- /Main Site -->


<!--include footer-->
  <%- include('include/_footer')%>
<!--/include footer-->
```

Comment: `profile_picture.data` is not a string, but an object, so check/show the code that creates `profile_picture` property

Comment: ok, I've added the mongo scheme and the controller.js in which I perform basic operations(create, get, update, delete)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding `profile_picture` property only when there's a file:

controller.js file:

```
//new user
const user = new Userdb({
// if there's `req.file`, add the property and all
   ...req.file && {profile_picture: {
        data: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname + '/../../uploads/' + req.file.filename)),
        contentType: 'image/png'
    }},
    name: req.body.name
    //...
```

also there's an extra `users[i]/` in the view, try this:

```
src="data:<%=users[i].profile_picture.contentType%>;base64,<%=users[i].profile_picture.data.toString('base64')%>">
```

**EDIT:**

convert object to buffer because it was casted to object:

```
<img src="data:<%=users[i].profile_picture.contentType%>;base64,<%=Buffer.from(users[i].profile_picture.data,'utf-8').toString('base64')%>">
```

Comment: unfortunately it gives the same error and it shows broken image icon

Comment: Thought I have to add that users[i]/ to provide better url since error occurred in browser says something about this but idk honestly

Comment: @DvdiidI remove all older records, and then try saving new data like this, you probably have something saved that got some object instead

Comment: I deleted all previous users, refreshed the app, refreshed the database, and tried to add a new user; still the same annoying error

Comment: I tried also to replace that source tag of the image with an URL of an online image; Still the same error; Do you have any idea what might cause this? maybe I had to add something in ejs to accept images or some restriction; I saw that I have to use app.use( express.static( "public" ) ); and image saved in public folder if it's about locally but that's not my case.

Comment: @DvdiidI it should work. try console.log data property. also, how do you pass data to the the view/render view

Comment: I added server, router, render and index files. All ejs files are in the views folder. Index.ejs is main where that ejs file form is inserted. I also replaced image with <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg"> just for testing and this one shows up just fine.

Comment: @DvdiidI aha, axios is casting it to object, so need to turn it into buffer check the edited part in the view, server doesn't need changes, adding that property conditionally can stay also, else you'd always store content type, even when there's no file, which was my first assumption

Comment: understood, ok; it worked! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @DvdiidI ok, great. I think it's actually .send, not axios, where it gets converted to json... rendering data without axios/api request should return buffer so your first implementation would work